# Is there a possibility that C++ multiple inheritance might be replaced with the Java interfaces?

Tags: java, c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have been studying a bit of Java and C++ more or less at the same time and I noticed that Java has a more friendly and intuitive way of interpreting the OOP than the C++ way.

Yes, Java is completely OO and, on the other hand, C++ supports many paradigms, but this doesn't mean that C++ couldn't improve its way of implementing the OO paradigm.

C++ supports multiple inheritance and Java translated it with multiple implementation (interfaces), which I find really intuitive and simple (I don't think that this is just an opinion).

My first question is in the title. I think that C++ would be more friendly, without losing practically a bit of its power. It's a question of improving a extraordinary programming language, which however is not perfect.

My second question is: what are the advantages of multiple inheritance compared to the interfaces of Java programming language (if any)?

Comment: So much code would break if this happened.

Comment: Nobody is stopping you from writing base classes with only abstract methods in C++.

Comment: One advantage is the opportunity for a tuple implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041447/how-is-stdtuple-implemented

Comment: What is the representation of tuples in Java?

Comment: @bad_alloc, Not sure. Multiple inheritance isn't the only way to implement them, but why disallow one method?

Comment: Everything does not mean perfection. Sometimes you have to give up something.

Comment: @bad_alloc: If you want your language to take away features for your own benefit, you really should be using Java and not C++.

Comment: I can certainly agree that C++ could do without multiple inheritance, even though it can be used for a few nifty tricks here and there. It's just one of these things that they had to choose early on, and now, it cannot and will not ever be changed because too much code would break, and you certainly cannot break all that code just for what is really a matter of opinion. BTW, many "professional" projects have, as a coding guideline, a rule about not using multiple / virtual inheritance, to keep things simpler, like in Java. In C++, you decide where you draw your lines.

Comment: @MikaePersson wrote: "In C++, you decide where you draw your lines."

Comment: If you still have to decide, you are continueing losing time

Comment: @bad_alloc, should we also add garbage collection to C, to make it more "friendly"?

Comment: I am not saying it. Who is talking about C?

Comment: Or C++, for that matter; the point was adding garbage collection to a language that currently lets programmers manage memory explicitly.  You're talking about removing a capability that programmers sometimes rely on, just because it's something extra to have to think about.  Limiting capabilities to make things easier is a characteristic of higher-level languages, but not all languages are high-level.  There's a whole spectrum.

Comment: I am not saying to add GC to C++, it has smart pointers, which tries to emulate GC (in slightly different way). Why? To make programming in C++ more easily and friendly.

Comment: With all the respect, why should my question be downvoted? It seems my question is surely stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple inheritance can be dangerous, but it's sometimes the most appropriate solution to a problem, and there's lots of software already written that uses it.  Removing multiple inheritance from C++ would break all that software, in a way that's not simple to fix.  Being compatible with existing code is more important than being "friendly".

If you want the effect of a Java interface in C++, just write a class that contains nothing but pure-virtual member functions, and derive from it using [virtual inheritance](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html) to "implement" it in another class.

Java was designed as a higher-level and simpler language than C++, and the tradeoffs between them are the same as between any high-level and lower-level language.  Java provides a bit less flexibility (e.g. single inheritance, little control over memory allocation) in exchange for being a bit easier to work with; C++ provides more power and flexibility at the cost of having to "know what you're doing" a bit more.  These differences are OK; there's no need to turn one language into the other.

Comment: The world needs all types...

Comment: I think that the world needs just some almost perfect types. People continue to create programming languages and sometimes not for a real useful reason.

Comment: No single language can be perfect, or even almost perfect, for all kinds of programs. There are lots of tradeoffs involved in any language design. You sound like you think Java is the solution to everything, and that's not the case.

Answer (score -1):

1. C++ is becoming more and more user-friendly with the updates, becoming bit by bit more like java, but it needs not to change too much not to wreck legacy code. The Boost library is more or less the pioneer of the c++ language, being the (probably) most used library of all times and taking an easier and more intuitive OO approach to c++. Features from the Boost libraries often get to the STD eventually.
2. Let's take this easy example : `class man` and `class parent` have respective functions `work` and `cry`. `class dad` inherits from both `man` and `parent`. Now you don't have to write `cry` twice when you write `class mom` which inherits from `class woman` as well as from `parent`.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's any more user friendly, it's just got more "stuff" that would otherwise require external library sources. That's the, IMHO, worst thing about C++ when compared to C# or Java. And the relationship goes both ways; C++ had lambdas before Java. Also, your simple example with in Java is just as easy, **but remember**, men and woman don't `cry()` the same way, so either way it's an override.

Comment: @Chief The point of multiple inheritance is when both men and women `cry()` the same way though

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid or tired, but why would you have that `cry`ing relationship. You start you example above the base class. Could be `class human`; all humans can cry. You've *already* written `cry` twice by including it in man *and* woman. Plus I'd use an `enum sex` and a `gender` var in `human` and bypass the spaghetti incident. Different strokes I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

1.Having multiple inheritance in a explicit way is seems to be more user friendly but actually it is not. There are lot of problem will be coming in the future if you do that i mean in your project for an instance knowingly unknowingly you will be adding the same code again and again to your final Class which makes your project more complicated and confuses the interpreter which method should be executed at the appropriate time.

1. Just consider in C++ you have 
   Class A
   {
        void display_a(){}
   }
   Class B A
   {
       void display_b(){}//this class contains 'display_a()' too
   }
   Class C A,B //multiple inheritance.
   {
      display_c(){} //this class contains two times 'display_a()' and one time 'display_b()'
   }

so class a contains two times 'display_a()' this is the problem we have in multiple inheritance in C++ so that we go for Interface in Java,which solve that problem.